# MongoDb Query: Based on all dates in date interval and additional condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My mongodb collection looks like this. Basically for each product_id, there are multiple documents to store the availability across various dates.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5bf22a773d3999bca17d4a3d"),
"timestamp" : ISODate("2018-12-30T18:30:00.000Z"),
"product_id" : "1",
"available" : true
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5bf22a773d3999bca17d4a3d"),
"timestamp" : ISODate("2018-12-31T18:30:00.000Z"),
"product_id" : "1",
"available" : true
}
```

How should I query so that, given a date interval availability is true for all the dates in that interval.

> Example: Date interval: 30-12-2018 To 31-12-2018 AND avalability: true should return 2 documents in this case, because availability is true on both these dates.
>   Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following, return all querys that have availability true and then with that array check filter the dates with a .filter, so the dates that interest you are between to parameters date1 < dateYouWant < date2.

Then return the array with the dates that interest you.

This two links will help you.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

What you could also do is use `filter({})` and in the query to search with the statements `$gt` (greater than) and `$lt` (less than) you'd put something like this:

```
`filter({ $and[{ date: {$gt: minimumDate }, {$lt: maximumDate}, {avaliability: true}] })`
```

and:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/

gt: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/

lt: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/

The **and** operator makes sure that you get the objects that satisfy both conditions

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Without `product_id`

db.collection.find({timestamp:{$gte:ISODate("2018-12-30T00:00:00.000Z"),$lte:ISODate("2018-12-31T23:59:59.000Z")}, available:true})

2. With `product_id`

   db.collection.find({timestamp:{$gte:ISODate("2018-12-30T00:00:00.000Z"),$lte:ISODate("2018-12-31T23:59:59.000Z")}, available:true, product_id:1})

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/

Comment: The above doesn't work because it returns matching documents even if available:true for even 1 record. Whereas I want to return results if available:true for all dates in the range or else no results.